# why am i getting the warning [unchecked] unchecked conversion?

Tags: java, warnings, unchecked-conversion

Can anyone please point me what I am missing over in the below statements?
**Warning 1**

```
 prog.java:16: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        adj = new LinkedList[v];
              ^
  required: LinkedList<Integer>[]
  found:    LinkedList[]
```

**Warning 2**

```
prog.java:18: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            adj[i] = new LinkedList();
                     ^
  required: LinkedList<Integer>
  found:    LinkedList
```

**Warning 3**

```
prog.java:43: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to push(E) as a member of the raw type Stack
        stack.push(new Integer(v));
                  ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class Stack
```

help me to recover this warning.Thanks in advance
PC :- keep_smiling

Answer (score 0):

warning 1 and 2 arises because you are not using generics properly.Cast your LinkedList to a generic type rather than raw type e.g `LinkedList <Integer>.`

I cant tell about the third as you should provide the code tempelate.

Comment: Thanks.How do i change this line my code to recover this warning?

Comment: Change it to LinkedList<Integer>

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using generic data-structures and your variables do not match the exact generic type where you are receiving the warnings. To be more accurate, it happens when the right-hand-side generic type is not the same or a sub-type of the left-hand-side generic type.

For example if you have:

```
List<String> x;
```

If you do something like:

```
x = new ArrayList();
```

You will get an unchecked warning, because `x`'s generic type, i.e. `String`, is not the same or a super-type of the right-hand-side generic type `Object` which is the default for List.

Comment: I actually used this.but still it show warning **MyCode** `private LinkedList<Integer> adj[];    adj=new LinkedList[V];`

Comment: `adj=new LinkedList[V]` is same as `adj=new LinkedList<Object>[V]` and Object is not the same or sub-type of `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

just put

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

above your method;

For example:

```
class Graph { 
    private int V;
    private LinkedList <Integer> adj[]; 

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Graph(int v) { 
       V = v; 
       adj = new LinkedList[v];
       for (int i=1; i<=v; i++) 
          adj[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
    } 
}
```

There is one problem here , when we use

```
adj = new LinkedList<Integer>[v]; rather than adj = new LinkedList[v]
```

the compiler throws error cannot use generic type, so by adding above condition @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") solves this problem.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to that?